# Ignoring overflow:hidden elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to calculate highlight masks for DOM elements for a webapp with in-page editing.  Since elements can change dimensions, the mask is calculated dynamically on hover.

One of the elements is an image scroller, so has an overflow:hidden with images inside an extra wide div.  The problem i'm having is getting jQuery to ignore elements with overflow:hidden in its width/height calculations.

In short: is there a jQuery selector to ignore DOM nodes hidden by overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a custom jQuery selector, like `even` or `odd` and you can name it `notOverflowHidden`

```
$.expr[':'].notOverflowHidden = function(obj){
   return ($(obj).css('overflow') !== 'hidden');
};
```

and you can get a collection of nodes with overflow property not hidden like so:

```
$('div:notOverflowHidden').each(...);
```

Comment: While the other answers are fine, this offers the necessary complexity and is the easiest to use with my existing code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYP8Z/

```
//for example I am selecting divs
 $(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('overflow')!='hidden')
            alert($(this).html()); //your action
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is ...

```
$("*").each(function(){
 //only pick those element from DOM whose css has overflow not equal to hidden
 if($(this).css("overflow") != "hidden"){
   //do your logic
 }
});
```

For more JQuery Selectors, please see the following link

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/